# Access only to one view,not other tabs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on Sql Server 2008 R2,and created a user to **only** access to one view.But the user access to security tab and linked servers too and it can edit the users!
so is it possible to **deny access to security tab** for users?

[image]